# Plotting histogram from a list of bin boundaries and counts

Tags: histograms, mathematica-online

If I use HistogramList (in mathematica) to create list of bin boundaries and bin counts from my data, can I use this list to plot histogram? I want to add the counts from various datasets before plotting my final histogram. So, I would like an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the documentation pages do a good job of placing a function within the entire Wolfram language ecosystem under the `Properties & Relations` section.

Indeed, in this case the relation to `Histogram` is the first example in that section:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
{BarChart[Last[HistogramList[data]]], Histogram[data]}
```

[image]