# Plotting histogram from a list of bin boundaries and counts V2

Tags: histograms

I would like to ask the very same question as
[Plotting histogram from a list of bin boundaries and counts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276340/plotting-histogram-from-a-list-of-bin-boundaries-and-counts), because I do not find it sufficiently answered.

"If I use HistogramList (in mathematica) to create list of bin boundaries and bin counts from my data, can I use this list to plot histogram? I want to add the counts from various datasets before plotting my final histogram. So, I would like an answer to my question."
Is it possible to precalculate the bin counts and directly use them in the `Histogram` function?

In the answer to the cited and closed question a reference is made to the help file, where it is proposed that using the `BarChart[Last[HistogramList[data]]]` yields the same result as `Histogram[data]`, which clearly isn't the case because the horizontal axis labeling is missing.

[image: Solution proposed as equal in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276340/plotting-histogram-from-a-list-of-bin-boundaries-and-counts.]

Comment: Thank you for this link, it certainly does.
It can also be achieved by my following proposition:
 `myhistogram2[hl_, options_] := 
 ListLinePlot[{{#[[1]], 0}, {#[[1]], #[[2]]}} & /@ 
   Transpose@{MovingAverage[hl[[1]], 2],
     Table[
      Total[hl[[2, ;; , i]]]
      , {i, 1, Length@(hl[[2, 1, ;;]])}]
     }, PlotStyle -> Orange, options]`

But it seems there is no native solution to it. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can use `WeightedData` with `Histogram` to obtain a histogram.

```
(* Generate some data and a histogram list *)
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
hlist = HistogramList[data];

(* Centers of bins *)
x = Table[(hlist[[1, i]] + hlist[[1, i - 1]])/2, {i, 2, Length[hlist[[1]]]}];

(* Plot the histogram *)
Histogram[WeightedData[x, hlist[[2]]], {hlist[[1]]}]
```

[image: Histogram using weighted data]

As a check construct a histogram with the raw data and same bin boundaries:

```
Histogram[data, {hlist[[1]]}]
```

[image: Histogram from raw data]

Answer (score 4):

You can use bin lists and counts returned by `HistogramList` as the second and third arguments in `Histogram` (with arbitrary fake data in the first argument):

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];

{bins, heights}  = HistogramList[data];

Histogram[{1}, {bins}, heights &]
```

[image]

```
Row[{
   Histogram[{1}, {bins}, heights &, 
      PlotLabel -> Style["Histogram[{1}, {bins}, heights &]", Black, 16],
      ImageSize -> 400], 
  Histogram[data, PlotLabel -> Style["Histogram[data]", Black, 16],
      ImageSize -> 400]}, 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Same method works for `Histogram3D`:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
data2d = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {200, 2}];

{bins2d, heights2d} = HistogramList[data2d];

Row[{Histogram3D[{{1, 2}}, List /@ bins2d, heights2d &, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Histogram3D[{{1,2}}, List/@bins2d, heights2d&]", Black, 16], 
  ImageSize -> 400], 
 Histogram3D[data2d, ImageSize -> 400, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Histogram3D[data2d]", Black, 16]] }, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!  That is short and sweet.  I see that `{1}` can be replaced with any list of numbers (real and even complex numbers!).  So `Histogram` essentially ignores the first argument when `heights` is followed by `&` ?

Comment: @JimB, yes, and same trick works for  `Histogram3D`.

Comment: Thank you @kglr!
This is exactly what answers the question. It should be suggested to be added to the official documentation, because it fills exactly the missing link.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for wanting to use `BarChart` isn't stated but if there's some need to do so, you can get essentially the same result as `Histogram`.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 200];
hlist = HistogramList[data];
labels = Table[ToString[(hlist[[1, i]] + hlist[[1, i - 1]])/2 // N], {i, 2,  Length[hlist[[1]]]}];
BarChart[Last[hlist], BarSpacing -> None, ChartLabels -> labels]
```

[image: Histogram with counts using BarChart]