# Is there a simple way to get histogram-styled plots from explicit data?

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have a bunch of data that lends itself to plotting as a histogram, but for various reasons I can't really use the built-in [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) function, and instead I have built binning code that returns output as a list of the form

```
{{bin1x,bin2x,...},{bin1value,bin2value,...}}
```

which is effectively what I would expect as an output from [`HistogramList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HistogramList.html) (if my data were suitable for [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)) to begin with).

**Is there a simple, built-in way to plot data in this format in a graphical way that matches the output of Histogram?**

In essence, I am hoping for a function `PlotLikeHistogram` that will factorize `Histogram` as `Histogram[data] ↔ PlotLikeHistogram[HistogramList[data]]`. Is this a thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a bar chart from a list of heights \*and\* bin delimiter positions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81155/how-to-create-a-bar-chart-from-a-list-of-heights-and-bin-delimiter-positions) Also: [Plotting histogram from a list of bin boundaries and counts V2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288168/plotting-histogram-from-a-list-of-bin-boundaries-and-counts-v2/288185).

Comment: "BarChart" will do what you want.